# Laravel/ PHP: Order by an integer column as alphabetically?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have an integer column in database and want to order data by that column, but not as number, as alphabetically.
What sql-based laravel code can solve this problem? (**I use mysql-mariaDB**)

Comment: Please share a code

Comment: This is very simple laravel code. I understood should use `->orderByRaw(...)` but don't know what sql code should be in raw sql in mysql-mariaDB?

Comment: _"I use mysql-mariaDB"_ - Are you using both or one of them in particular? They might work the same in most cases (since MariaDB is based on MySQL), but they are not the same. It's always best to be as specific as possible, since they actually have diverged from each other.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY to_char(my_int_column, '99999')` works with PostgreSQL.

`ORDER BY cast(my_int_column as CHAR(10)` might work with some other databases.

Edit:
`ORDER BY cast(my_int_column as CHAR)` seems to be correct for MySQL

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work in mysql-mariaDB, if I don't mistake